# I want to replace common data of base array data and temp array,with temp array data to maintain order of temp array in base. Same structure of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

trying to replace base array with data as sorted in temp array which is common, using splice
method to replace at i index with temp data
Same structure of objects are there in array. On basis of temp I have to sort base array
`

```
var base = [
          {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"},
          {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "1b"},
          {range: "3.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "6e"},
          {range: "2.4", date: "May 16 2022", id: "a1"},
          {range: "2.3", date: "May 16 2022", id: "3b"},
          {range: "2.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "4f"},
          {range: "2.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "fe"},
          {range: "2.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "ce"}
        ]
        var temp = [
          {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "1b"},
          {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"}
        ];

    Have tried this
        for(var i = 0; i< base.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j<temp.length; j++) {
                if(base[i].id === temp[j].id) {
                    base.splice(i, 1, temp[j]);
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
    `
    expected result is as below
      {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "1b"},
      {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"},
      {range: "3.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "6e"},
      {range: "2.4", date: "May 16 2022", id: "a1"},
      {range: "2.3", date: "May 16 2022", id: "3b"},
      {range: "2.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "4f"},
      {range: "2.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "fe"},
      {range: "2.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "ce"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For loops use semicolons not commas, eg `for (let i = 0; i < thing; i++)`
2. Neither of your arrays contain elements with an `_id` property, just `id`.
3. I removed the `break` after the splice.  Not sure if that was required.

```js
var base = [
  {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"},
  {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "eb"},
  {range: "3.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "6e"},
  {range: "2.4", date: "May 16 2022", id: "a1"},
  {range: "2.3", date: "May 16 2022", id: "3b"},
  {range: "2.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "4f"},
  {range: "2.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "fe"},
  {range: "2.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "ce"}
];

var temp = [
  {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "1b"},
  {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"}
];
    
for(var i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
      if(base[i].id === temp[j].id) {
          base.splice(i, 1, temp[j]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(base);
//expected result is as below
//  {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "eb"},
//  {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"},
//  {range: "3.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "6e"},
//  {range: "2.4", date: "May 16 2022", id: "a1"},
//  {range: "2.3", date: "May 16 2022", id: "3b"},
//  {range: "2.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "4f"},
//  {range: "2.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "fe"},
//  {range: "2.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "ce"}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still  see the output as below. 
  [{
    "range": "3.1",
    "date": "May 16 2022",
    "id": "e1"
  },
  {
    "range": "3.2",
    "date": "May 16 2022",
    "id": "eb"
  },
  {
    "range": "3.0",
    "date": "May 16 2022",
    "id": "6e"
  },
 ...]
Sort order of temp array should be followed

Comment: Only one element of the temp array is used, though.  There is no match for id="1b" in the base array.

Comment: Have edited as u suggested, sorry new in writing question, below is my base array that I mentioned above, 
var base = [
          {range: "3.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "e1"},
          {range: "3.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "1b"},
          {range: "3.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "6e"},
          {range: "2.4", date: "May 16 2022", id: "a1"},
          {range: "2.3", date: "May 16 2022", id: "3b"},
          {range: "2.2", date: "May 16 2022", id: "4f"},
          {range: "2.1", date: "May 16 2022", id: "fe"},
          {range: "2.0", date: "May 16 2022", id: "ce"}
        ]